# How did 'arithmetic' come to current pronunciation (or spelling)?

Tags: historical-linguistics, orthography

I am talking about 'th' that represents /θ/ sound.

Wiktionary states, that the word 'arithmetic' is borrowed at some stage from French 'arsmetike'. I can imagine that at some moment the word came to be spelled more like Latin 'arithmetica' under the Latin influence as science lingua franca.

Still, neither French nor Latin word was pronounced with /θ/ sound. Should I assume this pronunciation emerged lately as spelling-influenced?

Actually, the question holds for every word with 'th' borrowed from Latin.

Comment: Well, its English form changed to restore its Greek origin (and its initial form in Latin), both of those had th.

Comment: I really never heard that some sound change happened _for the purpose_ of restoring origin of a word.

Comment: You should not assume that the pronunciation of the word reflects continuous oral transmission from French into everyday English. Rather, there is a simple spelling rule that "th" is pronounced [θ].

Comment: @OlegRybkin, this is a well-known phenomenon (among linguists). Other examples where "etymological" spelling was restored: **debt** - Middle English det(te); **receipt** - Middle English receiht etc.; **salmon** - Middle English samo(u)n etc. The word **island** is a classic example, cf. OE ígland (íegland), íland.

Comment: @OlegRybkin you said "some sound change happened for the purpose of restoring origin of a word" - I mean it spelling was changed, not its pronunciation.